# WSO2 APIM storing files in gov registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have another question on WSO2 APIM 2.6.0

I am working in one scenario where I have to store one file which is in json in gov registry. I can do that manually from the dashboard but I am looking for a way to perform that using API or in automated way.

Research done till now

1) Checking on the link which ideally enable WSO2 ESB to maintain a remote registry. But I am unable to get how the registry DB will be shared between the applications (APIM and ESB).
Like, ESB has property where we can store the data in registry directly from proxy or an API and also enables us to retrieve them accordingly.
But how do we do in APIM to store the file with json content.

Any suggestions here.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Using+the+Registry+REST+API